# Why does my lambda function not return any value when functions like filter() and map() are used on it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I am using Jupyter notebook, and for practice want to use the `lambda` and `filter` functions in my code to filter the even numbers out of a given list, consisting of numbers from 1 to 10.

The code shows what I have attempted to do, but the output is not what I expected.
I left the code for a while, and tried using a `map()` function, this time to square the values of the list, but it too isn't giving a proper output.

The `filter` code:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
evenNumbers = filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, l)
print(evenNumbers)
#response
<filter object at 0x000002023F87F5F8>
```

The `map` code:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
squaredNumbers = map(lambda x: x ** 2, l)
print(squaredNumbers)
#response
<map object at 0x000002023F85BA90>
```

I expected the output to be the values `2, 4, 6, 8, 10`, and a list of squares in the second case. Instead, the code is giving me the above responses. I am pretty sure that the problem is in `lambda`, but what is it?

Comment: No, that's correct. Those methods return lazy objects that produce results as needed, not lists. Give the returned objects to `list` to get a forced result.

Comment: ...or iterate over them

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes, I just viewed the page. But thanks for the response nonetheless!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the docs of [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) (the same goes for `filter()`), it clearly states:

> Return an **iterator** that applies function to every item of iterable ...

So this is the expected behaviour, as it does not calculate all elements in one go (saves memory and CPU time), but waits till you need them:

```
>>> map(lambda x: x ** 2, l)
<map object at 0x7f375ec905f8>
```

You can iterate over the result:

```
>>> for e in map(lambda x: x ** 2, l):
...     print(e)

1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
100
```

or convert it to list or tuple:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: x ** 2, l))
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

Comment: So lambda simply performs the function and waits till we ask it to give the value, right? Thanks for the help @Ralf !

Comment: No, `lambda` returns a value imediately when being called; `map()` and `filter()` are the ones that wait to invoke your `lambda` function until you ask for the next value.

Comment: Right, so the value sort of stays 'invisible' and the `map()` and `filter()` functions invoke it and sort of 'reveals it', right?

Comment: Well, functions like `map()` store the `lambda` function inside and call it once for each value of the iterable. When you ask for the first value, `map()` passes the first value of the input iterable to `lambda` and returns the result, but then it waits till you ask for the next value (no calculations are done in advance).

Answer (score 0):

If we try executing those set of statements in both python2 and python3,

for `filter()`,

the output of python2 will be ~ `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`

whereas, the output of python3 will be ~ `<filter object at 0x1014ba240>`

Similar will be the case with `map()` as well.

The reason is that those functions return a **list in python2**, whereas, **in python3, they return an iterator**.

To be able to use their result as in python2, all you have to do is convert it to a list before using the result.